# how to fix this 'Attempted to send a key down event when no keys are in keysPressed.'?

Tags: flutter, dart

When ever I click the button to play `note1.wav` this error occurred

```
Exception caught by services library ══════════════════════════════════
Attempted to send a key down event when no keys are in keysPressed. This state can occur if the key event being sent doesn't properly set its modifier flags. This was the event: RawKeyDownEvent#3f615(logicalKey: LogicalKeyboardKey#00000(keyId: "0x1100000000", keyLabel: "", debugName: "Key with ID 0x01100000000"), physicalKey: PhysicalKeyboardKey#700e3(usbHidUsage: "0x000700e3", debugName: "Meta Left")) and its data: RawKeyEventDataAndroid#4cb08(flags: 8, codePoint: 0, plainCodePoint: 0, keyCode: 0, scanCode: 125, metaState: 0)
'package:flutter/src/services/raw_keyboard.dart':
package:flutter/…/services/raw_keyboard.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 668 pos 7: 'event is! RawKeyDownEvent || _keysPressed.isNotEmpty'

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

please give me solution

Comment: is this issue getting in Linux web?

Comment: I am also facing this problem. please help someone

Comment: can you share your code?